# check if hebrew query exist in mysql db returns false

Tags: php, mysql, database, where-clause, hebrew

So my problem is like this:

I have a mysql database that contains information in hebrew, each row has a column named "name".

When I send a hebrew query to the server (by submit GET) i'm asking the php page to find the row where the name equals to that query.

The server just can't find it even though it's there.

If i'm looking for a query in english (that is in the db) the server do find it, and writes the valid information from the db. This information is also in hebrew.

By the way, I can see that the hebrew query I send is fine.

<s>I'm not posting any code for now but if you can't figger out what I can do (beside jumping of a roof) just ask me for one.</s>

**Ok, so as ask, here is a bit of code:**

```
<?php
$one=mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","PASSWORD");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'hebrew'");
if(!$one)die('An error has occured.');
else{
mysql_select_db("xxx_db", $one);
$two=strtolower($_GET[SearchQuery]);
$three=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xxx_table
WHERE name='$two'");
$four=mysql_fetch_array($three);
if($four)echo 'found';
else echo 'not found';
mysql_close($one);}
?>
```

Beside that, all of the table's columns are set to utf8_general_ci. Should I change it?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: How can you possible expect people to figure it out if you aren't posting any code?

Comment: what's the page's encoding? and if the database is utf-8, and your page is utf-8, you don't need to set the character set to hebrew.

Comment: I didn't set the general page encoding, because when I do set it (to utf-8) I just get gibrish for some reason. @DvirVolk

Comment: ok but what _is_ it? the fact you didn't set it doesn't mean it's not set. if you're reading hebrew it's either utf-8 or windows-1255. if it's windows-1255 do yourself a favor and move your app yo be unicode using utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

Your database or table's encoding is different than the page's encoding. the browser sends the data in the encoding the page has set (probably utf-8?), but either your database stores it otherwise (utf-16 maybe?), or there's a double conversion being done in the mysql client.
what are the settings on your MySQL?
run

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
```

to see what's going on.
also, are you using LIKE or a mysql full text index?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing code, but I suspect this is probably a character encoding issue. I've run into similar problems in the past with a table containing place names that had non-ascii characters. There are plenty of pages that give advice on setting up a MySQL database to be unicode friendly, such as:

http://www.richnetapps.com/php-mysql-speak-unicode/

or

http://www.tanzilo.com/2008/10/13/php-mysql-unicode-solution-to-chinese-russian-or-any-language/